# Center a dynamic square div based on height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div that is:

a) square
b) dynamically sized based on the height of the window
c) centered in the window (vertically and horizontally)

And I can't seem to get all three at once. I've looked a lot around SO and none of the tricks (`display:table-cell`, `:before` element, etc.) seem to work for me. The closest I've gotten can be seen in these two JSFiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/LN78N/ and http://jsfiddle.net/EKarx/, both of which seem fine until you try to resize the window.

The weird thing is, though, that if you run the JSFiddle again once it's resized, it finds the right shape and size, so I think I've run into some kind of feedback loop where the box will render just fine, but won't reflow properly.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, whether it's about why this happens or how to accomplish what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need it to be truly *square*, as in same width as height?

Comment: I don't think you can do this without using a javascript solution.  The problem is that if you only resize the window in 1 direction and both height and width properties are set to 100%, one can be greater than the other.  What you can do is attach an event handler to the window.resize function and have it set both width and height to whatever percentage is smaller on resize.

Comment: The idea is to have it be as square as possible. This has also crossed over from being an implementation issue to being an academic one: Is it possible to satisfy these three requirements in only html/css with the tools that work cross-browser today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy to do this using the [`vh` unit](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) from CSS3 Units and Values ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxJes/) in modern browsers):

```
.square {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 60vh;
    margin: 20vh auto;
}
```

Comment: Nice! It would also be nice if we lived in a world of modern browsers. :-)

Comment: This is a great solution! I wish it were implemented across the board, but I may have to use it for now and hope more support follows.